# Can't Download Aptana Studios Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Whenever I try to install the Eclipse Plugin for Aptana Studios, it just takes me an error page that says the following:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>78058BA4B693CC5F</RequestId><HostId>0wTEx1IV9xT7RNYa9KtVvevQaLUvkgzMu3ujvR/H6em6B3h3p9IQvT7KJszOU+yQ</HostId></Error>
```

What is going on here? Is this project still being supported?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you find anywhere where you can download the plugin?

Comment: Nope, I think it's been discontinued